# MYSQL insert and delete at the same time IMPACT

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, scheduled-tasks

Here is the scenario.

1. I have a schedule job running every minute which inserts data into a MYSQL table "demo". The total number of records per day are 60*24 = 1440.
2. Table demo already has 55000 records.
3. I want to clean records less than today's date. Therefore I am using below code to do the work daily at 10.00 AM.

---

```
$demo = Demo::whereDate('created_at','<', Carbon::today());

if(count($demo) > 0)
   {
     $demo->delete();
   }
```

Now a point will come where at the same time I am inserting to the same table and deleting from the same table.

I want to know that it will be safe? Or there will be an error or any other impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this will be an issue, since `Carbon::today()` returns `00:00:00` as time and you are executing the deletion job at `10:00:00`. Only records that are inserted more than 10 hours ago will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, there should not be any problem. If there are two requests at the same time MySQL server will handle them by itself. The same thing happens when a website is loaded. There is a lot of call at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. Imagine you made 1000 requests per minutes, no one of them will overwrites an other one.